# sonarqube cannot access the online help and tips log in

Tags: sonarqube

I cannot access the "InstallingSonarQube" link in the docs.sonarqube.org page, and the url is: http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6951188

i tried to sign up, after login with this account, the docs server tips Not Permmited.

anybody knows why?

Comment: I'm seeing the same. I could acess the docs earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

That was a temporary production issue. It's fixed now. Sorry for the inconvenience.